# Undo custom git command settings

Tags: git, github, git-push

i am new to git and I made recently a change to the push command of git. I have overwritten the push command to be able to push from every branch just simple with git push. But unfortunately I didn't know at that time what I am doing ... :) And now my pushs are not shown correctly in my github.

So where are those custom overwrites saved and how can I undo this and return to the original push command?

Hopefully someone can help me with this.
Thanks.

Comment: Why did you want "to push from every branch just simple with git push" at all? The current default for the `push.default` setting which controls exactly this is `matching` which is -- to cite the manual -- "push all branches having the same name in both ends", exactly what you wanted.  In either case, next time consider that overriding an existing command, *changing its semantics,* is the last thing to consider; you would be way better off creating an `pushall` alias or something like this.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look if you made your changes for a specific project or globally. To do that:

```
git config --global -l
```

If you see a line with push.default, that means you changed it globally. If it is global, use the --global flag for the following command, else change directory to your project and run the command from there:

To remove a setting:

```
git config (--global) --unset <config name>
```

To remove your modified default push behaviour:

```
git config (--global) --unset push.default
```

Answer (score 1):

look at `.gitconfig` in your home directory for global git settings affecting all clones, especially the alias section in your case.